# How can I see my js lines which gets error in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser

I see errors or warnings But I can't see my js lines which gets error and I can't debug.

[image]

Note:
Js lines are in a html file, not external

Comment: use the `debugger` keyword in your code where you think the error might be occuring

Comment: make sure to enable developer-console by pressing `F12` to trigger `debugger`

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD where do I use the debugger keyword in my code?

Comment: @Ibnelaiq I'm so sure :) thanks anyway

Comment: in the js lines, if you don't know which method or section is causing issues, you can place it at the start

Comment: I don't understand anything, could you leave any link about this?